# Moderating Edge-Case Questions which can belong on Multiple Sites

Tags: discussion, moderation, migration

This question counts as an edge-case question: [How to organize a block of text in 8-character lines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53631/how-to-organize-a-block-of-text-in-8-character-lines)

Such an edge-case question can be considered extremely loosely on-topic for AskUbuntu.  However, it is fully on-topic for StackOverflow or Unix&Linux.

In such edge cases as these, what is the moderation/migration policies relating to such questions?  Subsequently, if a question is found to be an edge case for AskUbuntu, but is fully on-topic for one other StackExchange site, what is the recommended *flagging action* that should be taken by a non-Moderator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's not *off-topic* we don't expect the user to take the time to learn about another site, get an account and so on. We only migrate if the question is off-topic. Otherwise, it's perfectly fine to ask a programming question on AU, as long as it relates to Ubuntu.

The right course of action I think is to remind them of the other site(s), in a comment. And let the user decide to move the question or not. (In the same manner, we don't move stack exchange question from askubuntu meta to meta.so anymore).

Hope that makes complete sense :)

Comment: remember the golden rule of question migration: Don't Migrate Crap! :) but seriously, only migrate things that are worthy of it. Please. :p